# Satellite Orbit-Sun Geometry of Sun synchronous Orbit

Tags: artificial-satellite, orbit, sun-synchronous, the-sun

What is the difference in satellite orbit-sun geometry of  *Sun synchronous* orbits of **6am local time** , **9 am local time** , **12 pm local time** ?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: No Sir. I am trying to improve my concept.

Comment: The angle of the orbit planes relative to the Earth-Sun line.